# With CJKutf8 package, any bold or italic fonts stop working in LaTeX

Tags: cjk

I regularly have to type documents with a mix of English for the main body of the text and Chinese characters for headers, footnotes and similar parts of the document. Until a few days ago this was never a problem, but now I am trying to run latex on the following example:

```latex
    \documentclass{article}
    
    \usepackage{CJKutf8}
    
    \begin{document}
    
    \begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{zhkai}
    代数几何 
    
    \textbf{Latin text}
    \clearpage
    \end{CJK*}
    \end{document}
```

and the text OUTSIDE CJK environments in latin characters always shows up as normal text. The same happens when I switch to italic, small caps or anything similar.

Comment: I guess one approach would be to use `ctex`.

Comment: Does `\textnormal{\bfseries ...}` solve the problem, though?

Comment: @Davislor Unfortunately I am forced to use CJK by the publisher. I checked your suggestion and the problem persists when using `\textnormal{\bfseries ...}`.

Comment: I unfortunately cannot seem to get this MWE to compile on TeX Live 2022 using PDFLaTeX. In LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX, I could not reproduce your bug. Does updating fix it? One workaround you might try is to wrap only your Chinese titles and footnotes in the `CJK` environment.

Comment: I could get it to work with XeLaTex by swapping to ctex as suggested. Although this is not a permanent solution, at least I can see how it should look. I guess I will try reinstalling the latex distribution and see if that helps.

Comment: I don't have the `zhkai` fonts, but if I change it to `min`, the text is in the expected bold face.

Comment: As I run this (Alpine Linux, TeXLive 2022, fully updated), it does not compile, and the problem does not appear in lualatex, as noted by Davislor.  Voting to close.

Answer (score 3):

## TL;DR

Reinstall TexLive with the offcial script. You can follow these steps https://puttym.github.io/update-texlive

This may be a problem with TexLive installed by Ubuntu apt.

## Details

I am experiencing the same issue since I upgraded my Ubuntu. I build the following code with "pdflatex example.tex"

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{CJKutf8}

\begin{document}

\begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{min}
代数几何

\textbf{Bold text}
\clearpage
\end{CJK*}
\end{document}
```

And the text does not appear in bold. If I remove the CJK stuff, and build again, then the text is bold. **The problem does not appear when I compile it on Overleaf**, so it is probably a problem with local TexLive or whatever installation

After reinstalling TexLive with the official guidance (no apt install), this is fixed.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I can confirm that this fix works. The official package must have some issues, but nothing to do with the font, so it is hard to diagnose.