# Bold face not working with CJK and ctex?

Tags: cjk

I had a document with a very few chinese and japonese characters. I recompiled my document recently, and noticed that bold face does not work anymore on latin characters.

I tried to re-install texlive on my Ubuntu 22.04 without success. Any other advices?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{CJKutf8}
% \usepackage{ctex}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
 \item not bold
 \item \textbf{sould be bold}
 \item \begin{CJK}{UTF8}{gbsn}手勢令\end{CJK}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Log here with LaTeX:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (TeX Live 2022/dev/Debian) (preloaded format=latex)
 \write18 enabled.
 Source specials enabled.
entering extended mode
(./toto.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2022-01-21>
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/CJK/CJKutf8.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifpdf.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/CJK/CJK.sty
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/CJK/mule/MULEenc.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/CJK/CJK.enc))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-dvips.def)
(./toto.aux) (/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/CJK/UTF8/UTF8.bdg)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/CJK/UTF8/UTF8.enc)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/CJK/UTF8/UTF8.chr)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/CJK/UTF8/c70gbsn.fd)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/CJK/UTF8/c70gbsn.fdx)
Missing character: There is no � in font gbsnu52!
[1] (./toto.aux) )
Output written on toto.dvi (1 page, 532 bytes).
Transcript written on toto.log.
```

Log with PdfLaTeX:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (TeX Live 2022/dev/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./toto.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2022-01-21>
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/CJK/CJKutf8.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifpdf.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/CJK/CJK.sty
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/CJK/mule/MULEenc.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/CJK/CJK.enc))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def)
(./toto.aux) (/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/CJK/UTF8/UTF8.bdg)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/CJK/UTF8/UTF8.enc)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/CJK/UTF8/UTF8.chr)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/CJK/UTF8/c70gbsn.fd)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/CJK/UTF8/c70gbsn.fdx)
Missing character: There is no � in font gbsnu52!
[1{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./toto.aux) ){/usr/shar
e/texmf/fonts/enc/dvips/cm-super/cm-super-ts1.enc}</usr/share/texlive/texmf-dis
t/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb></usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/arphic
/gbsnu/gbsnu4e.pfb></usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/arphic/gbsnu/gbsnu62.pfb></usr
/share/texmf/fonts/type1/public/cm-super/sfrm1000.pfb>
Output written on toto.pdf (1 page, 35698 bytes).
SyncTeX written on toto.synctex.gz.
Transcript written on toto.log.
```

---

[Italic, bold and similar font types stopped working with CJKutf8 package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/642824/italic-bold-and-similar-font-types-stopped-working-with-cjkutf8-package)

The current version of texlive in the Ubuntu packages seems to be outdated. Manually upgrading texlive from https://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html sould be working.

I am not sure exactly what is wrong with the ubuntu packages, tough. I'll be glad to get some explanations.

Comment: show your log-file.

Comment: log file in the answer

Comment: add the log to the body of your question instead of adding it as an answer

Comment: sorry, here it is!

Comment: why do you use latex instead of pdflatex? And how to you process the dvi further for viewing?

Comment: Same thing happens with pdflatex. I use LaTeX because there are some minor differences and I prefer the latex then dvips then ps2pdf.